# How to use a CSS Framework with Yesod?

Tags: css, haskell, blueprint-css, yesod

I want to use the Blueprint CSS Framework with Yesod. Are there any best practices?

Because Yesod uses templates for CSS, it looks to me that I cannot use the .css-files directly? Do I have to rename them to .lucius-files?

How do I add the CSS to the defaultLayout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to rename them to .lucius files, which *should* work perfectly. (If it doesn't, it's a bug in Lucius and you should report it.) But you could also store the CSS in the static folder and reference it with an addStylesheet call; this is the approach I took with the Yesod Wiki, for instance.

Comment: In case of a CSS framework, it looks like best practice is placing them in the static folder.

Answer (score 4):

The yesod wiki has an [article](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/yesod_tutorial-filling_in_the_layout) about this. The solution is basically to put a copy of blueprint in your statics folder, then you can in a type safe way reference to blueprint like this (in your `templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet`, before `^{pageHead pc}`):

```
<link rel=stylesheet media=screen href=@{StaticR blueprint_screen_css}>
<link rel=stylesheet media=print href=@{StaticR blueprint_print_css}>
```

Comment: Link to article seems to be broken.