# How do i prevent caching of static files in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I use the scaffolded site and whenever i change something in the static javascript files i have to stop the development server and do a 'cabal install && yesod devel' for the changes to take effect.

Is there a way to use the *normal* js/css instead of the cached versions so i don't need to recompile all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
touch Settings/StaticFiles.hs
```

It is that particular file because the template haskell code for static files is in that file (in the default scaffolded structure). Touching that file will recompile it and reexecute the template haskell code.

---

edit: Sorry, I noticed this doesn't answer your question regarding how to develop with the static js/css source files like you do with the files in the `templates` folder. Well, you should not have js/css files in your `static` folder, please consider moving your `.js`/`.css` files to the `template` folder and use the shakespearian languages if you feel you're actively working on the css and js files.

You only put the js/css files in the `static` folder when you've taken a large code base from somewhere else, like the blueprint css framework. See my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562065/how-to-use-a-css-framework-with-yesod/9133295#9133295) question.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I just moved my js to the templates folder and it already makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [wiki entry](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Develop-JS-without-recompiling-the-yesod-project) on this now - at least the part about not having to recompile your yesod project whenever there's a javascript change.